# Django Nested Dictionary in Template, Test for End Node

Tags: django, templates, recursion

I need to process a nested dictionary in a template, performing one operation on an end node, and acting recursively if the node has children.

snippets/recursion.html

```
{% for k,v in dict.items %}
    {% if v.has_children %} <<<< [A] WHAT IS THE CHECK HERE IF THE NODE HAS CHILDREN????
        {% include "snippets/recursion.html" with dict=v %}
    {% else %}
        <h2>{{k}}</h2>
        {{v}}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

In the above [A], how do I check the value for each dictionary entry, to see if it is another dictionary and not terminal?

Comment: Did the answer solved your problem.?

Comment: @Satyajeet yes it did, thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use if with `dict.items`

```
{% for k,v in dict.items %}
    {% if v.items %} 
        {% include "snippets/recursion.html" with dict=v %}
    {% else %}
        <h2>{{k}}</h2>
        {{v}}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```